# How can I simply and quickly upload just 1 photo from my iPhone to a PC or Mac?

Tags: iphone, icloud, photos.app, photos, photo-stream

This is really frustrating. Occasionally, my work requires me to upload a photo from my iPhone (ios7) to a clients PC or Mac. I used to simply email it to my Gmail account and download it from the web but for whatever reason I can no longer do this (seems I can no longer email something to my self via Mac mail).

I've got Photostream set up but I cant access it via iCloud - theres just no photo option.

Obviously my clients PCs dont always have iPhoto (which is a huge pain to use anyway).

Why isnt there a simple way to transfer a photo from my phone to a computer via Bluetooth or USB?

Is there just a simple, non-proprietry software solution for transferring just 1 photo between devices?

Answer (score 1):

You can email it as an attachment to another email address. For emailing single photos, I got around this problem by setting up a secondary email account and emailing it to myself there. Then I checked the email account from my laptop. For multiple pictures, I had to use a windows machine (Windows 7). I just plugged the iphone into the PC's USB and it worked, reading it as a data drive.

It may also work to save it as an attachment in a draft message. Then synch accounts and look in the drafts folder of your computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Pushbullet](https://www.pushbullet.com/). You can send just about any message or file between a phone and a computer extremely simply. The catch is that the receiver of the pushbullet must have the Pushbullet chrome extension installed.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to use [Box](http://box.net) or [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com). If you're looking for a "just works" solution, iCloud drive in iOS 8 and OS X 10.10 Yosemite would also work.